# Most efficient way to build single-element list from string with or without spaces?

Tags: python, string, list

One way to convert a string to a single-element list in python is: `my_string.split()`. However, this will return a list with multiple elements if the string has spaces. What's an efficient way to create a list from a string that may or may not have spaces?

Comment: *The typical way to convert a string to a single-element list in python is: my_string.split()*: Who told you that?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the `.split()` method is "typical" or "common". If you can find a source that recommends this, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: If you really meant `l = [my_string]` then you should work on your ability to ask the right question... :-)

Comment: I've come to associate the brackets with a list comprehension that entails some loop, and possibly a conditional. No need to be obnoxious about it and make unwarranted generalizations, JPG; you may want to work on your attitude.

Comment: @Lamps1829 if you had written in your question what your desired output is, then you already would have had the solution. This is not about "converting a string to a list" (your words). This is making a string the one and only element in a list.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke The question title says *build **single-element** list* :-)

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke - I expressed in words, not code, what my desired output was. Dominic provided the code to match those words, and given that this was the first reply, and a quick one, the phrasing of my question seems to have been just fine.

Comment: Yes, yes, I get your point. But you also have to agree, the whole thing went like this. *A*: How do I get an egg into a bucket? *B*: Just put the egg into the bucket. *A*: Ah, didn't think of that.

Comment: I explained above that I've grown unaccustomed to using a particular syntax for a certain purpose (and thus, totally overlooked it) because I typically associate it with slightly different usage. I get the impression that you're trying to justify your initial churlish reply...

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, Lamps1829 Come on guys, calm down. How's the reply churlish? He added a smiley :-)

Comment: Alright, alright. No hard feelings. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just

```
l = [my_string]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to split up each character in the string into an element in a list? How about this:

```
>>> list("mystring")
['m', 'y', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']

>>> list("my string")
['m', 'y', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```